# Halachic registration of people's names

Tags: halacha-theory, names

Following the discussion about people's names in Halacha,

**Is there any obligation and a way of registering names in the Halacha**?

Is there an authority responsible for registering names - a Bais Din or a Rabbi of the community, whose job is to register the babies names and the changes and share them between the communities?

For example, I was born Eli - who's witnessing that I'm Eli? And what if tomorrow I move to Tel Aviv and call myself Hayim? Then two people know me by different names and they can't testify in capital crimes or Kiddushin and Gittin.

I know that the IDs is a very recent invention, but how the Halachah addresses that?

Comment: "and they can't testify in capital crimes or Kiddushin and Gittin" Huh? What does your name have to do with testimony?

Comment: @DoubleAA THis is off-topic, I only mentioned examples. You might answer that that is not needed of registration as there's no importance to the names.

Comment: People with multiple names is an old problem https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Gittin.4.2?lang=bi

Comment: With reference to moving to a different location, I believe that a person's name/identity is is established by using it for 30 days.

Comment: When a proper Sanhedrin is established (and may it be soon!) I'm sure there will be a whole department of functionaries to deal with this issue

Comment: What would be the point, if not for just tracking people? The world functioned for thousands of years without this.  The only reason we have this today is for governments to track people entering and leaving countries, and for applying social services to people.  Theoretically, if you didn't use medical aid, didn't travel you wouldn't any ID.

Comment: @IsraelReader Why one is not obligated to register with a local Beis Din?

Comment: @DannyF Whe Jewish legal system is based on names - Mamonos, Ishus, criminal etc. If there's no system of registering names the rest of the system is, how do I put it gently?

Comment: @AlBerko  Needing to register with a local authority when moving to a new location is reminiscent of dark regimes. Beis Din's mission did NOT include tracking the people entering and leaving their regions.